# centos restarting a service and its dependencies

Tags: systemd, services

I've set up 4 services which must be started in a specific order. Let's say:

serv1 => serv2 => serv3 | serv4

The order for serv3 or serv4 is not important, provided that both of them are started after serv2.

So I build the following service files:

### serv3.service (serv4.service is similar):

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts serv3
After=network.target serv1.service serv2.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/services/serv3start.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/services/serv3stop.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### serv2.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts serv2
After=network.target serv1.service

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/services/serv2start.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/services/serv2stop.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### serv1.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts serv1
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/services/serv1start.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/services/serv1stop.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `.sh` scripts are nothing but one-line script files, each one starting/stopping a different **java program**.

So far, so good.

The problem is: when I restart serv3 or serv4 (for example, by `systemctl restart serv3`) all of the four services are restarted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo that the unit file for service 3 contains `serv1start.sh`? Assuming it uses `serv1stop.sh`: Does that script somehow interact with the other services? What happens, if you stop services 3 and 4?

Comment: Oh, and the script doesn't interact with any other services. It just starts/kills the java program it's supposed to.

Comment: I tested it again. I was wrong: if I stop services 3 or 4, all of the others restart. If I start services 3 or 4 again, all of the others restart too.

Comment: Does that also happen if you remove the `Restart` part in the service files?

Comment: @Thomas, I took away the restart of serv3, serv1, and serv2. When I restarted serv3, I stopped serv1 and serv2 and they didn't restart automatically - I had to restart each one. But it seems this parameter is a clue in the right direction. I must be doing something wrong and I haven't found out what it is yet. I have only this four custom services and, in fact, any one of them I restart fires a restarting of all of the others.

Comment: Maybe you want to test with `Restart=on-failure`.

Comment: Perhapt the problem is not in the init system but in the application itself. Assume service2 is something like `netcat -l`: It starts, listens, gets a connection from service3 but as soon as service3 closes the connection it exits.

Comment: I'll do some more tests, but I think I found it: `Type=forking`. Aparently all my custom services have the same parent process (???) and when I restart one of them... I'll change to `Type=simple`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling 2 days with it, it ended up that the problem was with `Type=forking`. Apparently, all of my services are forks of some common parent process and when I restarted one of them, I was really restarting the parent process, which in turn restarted the others.

If anyone gives me a complete explanation to that, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

I think the key is the `.sh` scripts that were firing up the java programs, all of them like:

```
#! /bin/sh
java -jar /path_to_java_program/java_program.jar&
```

Now, as my java programs have an embedded start script, I'm just doing something like (in all of them):

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts java_program
After=network.target and other dependencies

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/path_to_the_java_program/java_program.jar
ExecStop=/usr/bin/services/serv1stop.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is the reason. The common parent of services managed by systemd is PID 1, `init`. And you don't restart that.

Comment: Any chance the java programs started by bash have the same common parent?

Comment: Within a service but not across systemd services.

Comment: Would it be a bug?

Comment: IMHO that is not even possible, even if you tried to create such a bug... Which observations make you think this is the case?

Comment: I cannot think of anything else that could lead the restarting of apparently unconnected services when you restart one of them (the only fact that connect all of them is that they are all custom services).

Comment: You can attach `strace` to the service and see what is really happening (i.e. whether it is killed by a signal and from where or it it exists on its own).

Comment: Oh... unfortunately I'm not authorized to stop the server to do more test and the IT guys haven't given me a test machine to try out different setups. Basically, I had to go with the first approach that worked fine in this case. I work mainly with SW development and fixing the services startup config was initially out of my scope, but as the IT department also doesn't have a Linux specialist, I took this issue to myself. But I think I can figure out a more simple setup, with another language but similar to what I have with java to see whether the problem was related to starting a java program.